# UILabel height depending on text

Tags: ios, swift, label

I am getting data from JSON and it changes for each view so I need the labels to change their height depending on their content and also the rest of labels and buttons should move down. I am using `sizeToFit` but anything else moves and when I scroll it loses its height and goes to 1 line again.
My labels have 0 lines in storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var titulares: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imagen: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var estilo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var historia: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// I get JSON Data

self.historia.sizeToFit()
self.titulares.sizeToFit()
self.estilo.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: are you using auto layout

Comment: I guess I am not... How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use autolayout
from the storyboard, press on a label and then in the right bottom side of the screen, you have the "Add new constrains" button.
Use it to set a spacing from a view to it's neighbors

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: Is that the button with a triangle? I had already added all the missing constraints

Comment: its the second from the right.
Looks like a square with lines on the right and left side (called Pin button).
Press it and then add the distance from neighbors at the 4 empty boxes.
Sorry for the edit

Comment: It is still not working, I pressed the 4 spaces to neighbors and also `constraints to margins`, `width`, `height` and `aspect ratio`

Comment: u r in the right place.
uncheck the constraints to margins.
if u want a label to be below another label, mark only the "top" distance.

Comment: Do I also have to add missing constraints?

Comment: usually, its recommended that u won't have any missing constrains

Comment: I did it, it is working but I have all the lines in red, is that normal?

Comment: Probably you have some conflicts. Try to solve them. (if you see a yellow / red triangle, press it and see all the conflicts you have)